# Apache Spark: JAR file not shipped on spark-submit

Tags: apache-spark, cluster-computing

Is it normal that Spark won't ship the JAR file (containing the spark application) automatically from master to slave? In earlier versions (and used on Amazon Webservices) it worked! Did this functionality change since version 1.2.2 or is the problem caused by clusters without public dns addresses??? Or is this "copy the jar automatically" function only working in an AWS cluster?

Here my submit call:

```
./spark-submit --class prototype.Test --master spark://192.168.178.128:7077 --deploy-mode cluster ~/test.jar
```

Info: the files listed by --jars parameter are "copied" to the workers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That was my own fault! -> don't use parameter --deploy-mode for usage of a standard cluster, where the driver process is planned to run on the master node.

See Spark documentation: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html

> --deploy-mode: Whether to deploy your driver on the worker nodes (cluster) or locally as an external client (client) (default: client) [...]
>
> A common deployment strategy is to submit your application from a gateway machine that is physically co-located with your worker machines (e.g. Master node in a standalone EC2 cluster). In this setup, client mode is appropriate. In client mode, the driver is launched directly within the spark-submit process which acts as a client to the cluster. The input and output of the application is attached to the console. Thus, this mode is especially suitable for applications that involve the REPL (e.g. Spark shell).
> [...]